# ASP.Net C# - Repeating code

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, repeat

I've got a number of different .aspx files that have the same following code in the Page_Load event.  Instead of repeating this in all the files, what is the best way to avoid this and instead have the code only in one place?

code:

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            int roleID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Role"]);

            if (roleID == 2)
            {
                Label1.Text = "tutor";
                ibtnApproveQuestions.Visible = true;
                ibtnCreateTest.Visible = true;
                lblRole.Visible = true;
                rblRole.Visible = true;
                rblRole.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Tutor", "T"));
                rblRole.SelectedValue = "T";
            }
            else if (roleID == 0)
            {
                Label1.Text = "admin";
                ibtnApproveQuestions.Visible = true;
                ibtnCreateTest.Visible = true;
                ibtnModifyUsers.Visible = true;
                lblRole.Visible = true;
                rblRole.Visible = true;
                rblRole.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "A"));
                rblRole.SelectedValue = "A";
            }
            else if (roleID == 9)
            {
                Label1.Text = "student view";
                lblRole.Visible = true;
                rblRole.Visible = true;
                rblRole.SelectedValue = "S";

                if (Session["PermanentRole"].ToString().Equals("tutor"))
                {
                    rblRole.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Tutor", "T"));
                }
                else if (Session["PermanentRole"].ToString().Equals("admin"))
                {
                    rblRole.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "A"));
                }
            }

            lblUsername.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
            lblEmailAddress.Text = Session["EmailAddress"].ToString();
            getModuleDetails();
        }
```

Comment: You do the same thing you always do, you extract the code to a method...

Comment: Either move the code to a shared/static method, use a derived base class, or implement a usercontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd consider placing this code in a master page, and then using that master page to build my child pages.

> ASP.NET master pages allow you to create a consistent layout for the pages in your application. A single master page defines the look and feel and standard behavior that you want for all of the pages (or a group of pages) in your application. You can then create individual content pages that contain the content you want to display. When users request the content pages, they merge with the master page to produce output that combines the layout of the master page with the content from the content page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100).aspx

The derived base class approach could work, but I think that, since you're going for consistency of appearance, the master page is your best option.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to show/hide UI elements based on some logic, and those elements are the same on many pages.  So put those elements in a single control, and just put that control on those pages.

Going further, it may well make sense to place this control in a master page that the these pages would all use.  Then you could add the control (and whatever else is common to all these pages) just once.

Comment: Not a terrible solution, but now you have to duplicate the **control** on every page.

Comment: @TerryLewis True.  This is making the assumption that you want to put it on many, but perhaps not *all* pages.  If it's going to be everywhere, you can put it in a master page or something similar.  I wanted to keep the answer simple, since the user is apparently a tyro, but, yeah, it makes sense to add it.  I went ahead an added a second paragraph mentioning this.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor those sections into different methods to isolate what is going on. Like this:

```
 protected void Page_Load( ...  )
 {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        int roleID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Role"]);

        if (roleID == 2)
        {
           SetTutor();
        }
        else if (roleID == 0)
        {
           SetAdmin();
        }
        else if (roleID == 9)
        {
            SetStudent();
        }

        lblUsername.Text = Session["Username"].ToString();
        lblEmailAddress.Text = Session["EmailAddress"].ToString();
        getModuleDetails();
    }


   private void SetTutor()
   {
        Label1.Text = "tutor";
        ibtnApproveQuestions.Visible = true;
        ibtnCreateTest.Visible = true;
        lblRole.Visible = true;
        rblRole.Visible = true;
        rblRole.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Tutor", "T"));
        rblRole.SelectedValue = "T";
   }
  }

   private void SetAdmin()
   {
            Label1.Text = "admin";
            ibtnApproveQuestions.Visible = true;
            ibtnCreateTest.Visible = true;
            ibtnModifyUsers.Visible = true;
            lblRole.Visible = true;
            rblRole.Visible = true;
            rblRole.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "A"));
            rblRole.SelectedValue = "A";
   }

   private void SetStudent()
   {
       Label1.Text = "student view";
            lblRole.Visible = true;
            rblRole.Visible = true;
            rblRole.SelectedValue = "S";

            if (Session["PermanentRole"].ToString().Equals("tutor"))
            {
                rblRole.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Tutor", "T"));
            }
            else if (Session["PermanentRole"].ToString().Equals("admin"))
            {
                rblRole.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Admin", "A"));
            }
   }
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but this doesn't answer the OP's question. You still have to duplicate the code across multiple pages.